# How to perform string manipulation while declaring env vars in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, environment-variables, pipeline, github-actions, building-github-actions

I have a github repository like the following

> **johndoe/hello-world**

I am trying to set the following environment variables in github actions

```
env:
  DOCKER_HUB_USERID: ${{ github.actor }}
  REPOSITORY_NAME: ${GITHUB_REPOSITORY#*\/}
  IMAGE_NAME_CLIENT: "$REPOSITORY_NAME-client"
  IMAGE_NAME_SERVER: "$REPOSITORY_NAME-server"
```

My expected results for these variables are:

```
johndoe
hello-world
hello-world-client
hello-world-server
```

But i am getting

```
johndoe
${REPOSITORY_NAME#*\/}
$REPOSITORY_NAME-client
$REPOSITORY_NAME-server
```

---

Looks like the expressions are not being evaluated while declaring the `env` vars.

How can I achieve the expected behavior?

Comment: For the second one, why not `${{github.repository}}`, similar to the first one that works? It looks like from [here](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Repository-name-in-environment-variable/m-p/38030/highlight/true#M3198) that would work.

Comment: `${{github.repository}}` includes the username... i want to get it without the username

Answer (score 24):

Shell parameter expansion is not possible outside of a `run` step.

```
env:
  REPOSITORY_NAME: ${GITHUB_REPOSITORY#*\/}
```

Create an extra step to compute the value into a new variable, appending it to the file at `$GITHUB_ENV`.

```
      - name: Set env
        run: echo "REPOSITORY_NAME=${GITHUB_REPOSITORY#*\/}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Test
        run: echo $REPOSITORY_NAME
```

Or create a step output.

```
      - name: Set outputs
        id: vars
        run: echo ::set-output name=repo_name::${GITHUB_REPOSITORY#*\/}
      - name: Test set output
        run: echo ${{ steps.vars.outputs.repo_name }}
```

Once the computed environment variable `REPOSITORY_NAME`, or step output `steps.vars.outputs.repo_name`, exists, they can be used to set other variables like this.

```
env:
  IMAGE_NAME_CLIENT: ${{ env.REPOSITORY_NAME }}-server
  IMAGE_NAME_SERVER: ${{ steps.vars.outputs.repo_name }}-server
```

Comment: `set-env` is deprecated since October 2020. The suggested replacement uses the `$GITHUB_ENV` file.

Answer (score 8):

Github has changed the way you set environment variables for security reasons, now you have to use this way.

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Set the environment variable
    run: echo REPOSITORY_NAME=${GITHUB_REPOSITORY#*\/} >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

then use it like this

```yaml
  - name: Use the value
    run: echo $REPOSITORY_NAME # This will output repository name
```

Example of use on env

```yaml
  - name: Install dependencies And Build Yarn and npm
    uses: fabiel-leon/npm-build@master
    env:
      REPO: ${{ env.REPOSITORY_NAME }}
```

```yaml
  - name: Build and push Docker images
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v1
    with:
      tags: ${{ env.REPOSITORY_NAME }}
```

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for either use it as `${{ env.REPOSITORY_NAME }}` or in a string `"This is my string ${{ env.REPOSITORY_NAME }}"`

Answer (score 4):

New as of this month, still in a 'run' - [Deprecating set-env and add-path commands](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/).

```bash
echo "action_state=yellow" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

I also found that things like `uses`/`with`/`ref` will not take `${action_state}` expansion, but they will take `${{ env.action_state }}` expansion after being stuffed.

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```
IMAGE_NAME_SERVER: "${{ REPOSITORY_NAME }}-server"
```